# Target the last child but not if it is the only child

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have only three paragraphs in a `div`, the result should be that the last paragraph is red.

But how do I ignore the the `last-of-type` result if there is only one paragraph in my `div`?

CSS:

```css
p:last-of-type {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Is it possible to use JavaScript or it has to be pure css?

Answer (score 5):

A combination of the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [:only-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type) [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) might work for this.

```css
.sample {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 1em;
}

p:last-of-type:not(:only-of-type) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample multiple">
  <p>first paragraph</p>
  <p>second paragraph</p>
  <p>third paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="sample single">
  <p>first paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I have only three paragraphs in a div, the result should be that
>   the last paragraph is red.
>
> But how do I ignore the the last-of-type result if there is only one
>   paragraph in my div?

By using the `:only-of-type` pseudo-class.

---

I'm not really (and never have been) a fan of the `:not` pseudo-class, so I usually employ the cascade to overwrite earlier rules, instead.

In this situation you can employ the cascade like this:

```
div p:last-of-type {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

div p:only-of-type {
color: initial;
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
float: left;
width: 150px;
}

div p:last-of-type {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

div p:only-of-type {
color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
</div>
```